# Selenium/PhantomJS sometimes won't load a new url after initial url

Tags: python, linux, selenium, phantomjs

I stripped down the code to show the core of what's happening here:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com/")
time.sleep(10) 
print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
time.sleep(10) 
print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)


driver.quit()
```

The output will show loading both pages on the first run, however after that it will only show loading the first given URL.  I can reverse the order, and it again will sometimes only load the first URL, not the second.  There seems to be no pattern as to when both URLs load.  Sometimes they'll both load multiple times without an issue, and then they'll only load the first url repeatedly.

I've also run this in the command line, while waiting between get() requests and have the same issue.

This is being run on a 64 bit Dreamhost VPS server, python 2.7, selenium 2.52, PhantomJS 2.1.1 for 64 bit linux.  When I run this code on my windows 7 machine with chromedriver I do not have this issue.

Comment: what is the purpose of adding `time.sleep(10) ` ? You really need that?

Comment: I'm new to how selenium and PhantomJS work, so I thought perhaps I had to add a wait period for the new page to load but it doesn't have any effect.  The lines outputting the title and url are in there for me to verify the  intended page has loaded.